# Android Project + Eclipse + Annotation Processing

Tags: android, eclipse, annotations, annotation-processing

Does anyone know how to enable annotation processing in Eclipse in an Android Project?
I did the following:

1. Created a Java Project with the Processor and the **META-INF > services** file with the class name of the Processor that i want to use;
2. Exported the Processor project to a .jar file;
3. Imported the Processor jar file to a folder (not /libs) and configured the project properties to enable annotation processing (Properties > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing).

If I remove the jar file from the folder, Eclipse reports an error in the project because the annotation processor was not found. But if the processor is in place and the Eclipse is configured, the processing does not occur.

If I use the same processor in a standard Java Project it works just fine.
Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, my android project won't process my annotation processor. My compiler compliance already set to 1.6, but nothing happens. When you said "Imported the Processor jar file to a folder", what do you mean? can you walktrough me? I am able to run my processor in normal java project....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

**The Project Properties must have the compiler compliance level set to no less than 1.6, or else the processor won't be executed...**

Answer (score 0):

i am using ADT23 with Eclipse Luna.
Go to your project properties and select `Java Compiler` and select you `Compiler Compliance Level` to 1.6.
Then your `Annotation Processing` option will be enable.
Create a folder `compile-libs` in your project, where your `lib` folder and paste `jar` file `androidannotations-3.0.1.jar` this location `compile-libs\androidannotations-3.0.1.jar` .

Add `androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar` in your project `libs\androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar` .

Finally, you must add both file path in your Factory Path.
e.g `{Your Project}/compile-libs/androidannotations-3.0.1.jar` and 
    `{Your Project}/libs/androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar`